# Obtaining Selected Value in React-Select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I'm trying to implement [this example that obtains the user selected value,](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-tftsha)  but using the async select version.

I want to obtain the value that the user selected, but going through the docs on react-select this isn't clear how to do. If you set state equal to the inputValue, as soon as you click on the 'submit' button the inputValue is cleared. You get back

`" "`

instead of

`user selected value`

I'm not sure how to obtain the user selected value using the async select component. I have my API data successfully populating & filtering the suggestions box, but I can't figure out how to get the selected value.

I've tried numerous methods and lastly tried using the refs approach like in the above link, but the stored value shows up as null. Instead of storing the user selected value. [Here is the link to my broken codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandboxer-example-spwmc).

Can anyone help or point me in the right direction?

### Edit

[Here is a link to a working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandboxer-example-nhjt3) if anyone gets stuck on this in the future.

Comment: It seems like their docs example doesn't work either?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, what you got wrong is props of react-select to get value on  on-change. Use `onChange` instead of `onInputChange` on your `AsyncSelect` Component. Both props are for different purpose. Here is a doc for all props available for react-select. https://react-select.com/props
Try code below

```
textChange = inputValue => { // whole object of selected option 
    this.setState({ inputValue:inputValue.value });
};

render(){
....
        <AsyncSelect
          defaultOptions
          loadOptions={this.promiseOptions}
          onChange={this.textChange} /** onChange triggers only when user change the
           options but onInputChange triggers on each change which is for different
           purpose like for e.g. when user type, fetch similar options **/
          name="options"
        />
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @saurssaurav! This was it and an easy fix. That explains why nothing was working with onChange (since it outputs an object of the selected value), but it was working with onTextChange (outputs a string of what the user is actually typing).  Cheers!